# Does $scope inherit properties from $rootScope? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have Angular (v1.2.8) application, where files look like:

Index.html

```
<div> Menu </div>
<div ng-view ></div>
<div> Footer </div>
```

PartialView.html

```
<div ng-controller='ItemsController'> ... </div>
```

App Configuration

```
itemsApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/items', {
        templateUrl: 'views/items/PartialView.html',
        controller: 'ItemsController'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/authentication/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/logout', {
        templateUrl: 'views/authentication/logout.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });
    ...
```

Controller

```
itemsApp.controller('ItemsController', function($scope, $rootScope, ConfigService) {
    ...
    if (!$scope.userConfig) {
        $scope.userConfig = ConfigService.getCurrentUserConfig();
        $rootScope.userConfig = $scope.userConfig;
    }

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.userConfig = null;
    }
    ...
});
```

I want to load specific configuration for each logged in user (Joe, Dave). But my problem is, when I log in with another user (Dave) I will get cofiguration of previously logged in user (Joe).

I don't get it, because when I logg out, the destroy callback is executed, where `$scope.userConfig = null;` is called

With a new user logged in (Dave), I would expect the `$scope.userConfig` to be null and therefore to run `$scope.userConfig = ConfigService.getCurrentUserConfig();`.

But instead, `$scope.userConfig` contains configuration of previously logged in user (Joe) and new configuration is not retrieved.

When I remove `$rootScope.userConfig = $scope.userConfig;` suddenly it starts working as excpected, why?

I want to save current user configuration into `$rootScope`, so I can retrieve it in other controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking for `if (!$scope.userConfig)` the following happens:

1. The $scope of the controller is looked at to see if it has the `userConfig` object. (on your first time, it does not have it currently, so you place your config on the `$scope`, and also on `$rootScope`).
2. When it is not found on `$scope`, it goes up the `$scope` chain, up to the `$rootScope` to look for it.

When you do: `$scope.userConfig = null;` on your destory event, it just assigns null to the `userConfig` object on **that** `$scope`, not on the `$rootScope` itself.

Next time when you enter the controller, and look for `$scope.userConfig`, it is in fact null on that `$scope`, but it goes up and finds it on the `$rootScope` and that's why you enter the `if` statement, so you need to remove it from the `$rootScope` as well on destroy.

Also think about whether or not you need it on both of these scopes, I would imagine the `$rootScope` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

From [controller documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

> The $scope that each Controller receives will have access to
>   properties and methods defined by Controllers higher up the hierarchy.

So when you ask for `!$scope.userConfig` is getting it from `$scope.$parent`, which can be $rootscope or not, depending where you locate the element using that controller.